# How to scan hidden/invisible bluetooth tag using Android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am new to Android development and I am developing an Android application to measure the distance between smartphone and a bluetooth tag.

I am using a rtrivr_621 bluetooth tag, but the problem is that my application scans any nearby bluetooth device except the tag. So it seems like it's hidden or something like that. I also tried to search for it using another application (called bluetooth scanner) and fortunately I could find it and know the MAC address.

I searched a lot and found the method `listenusinginsecurerfcommwithservicerecord()`, but I don't know exactly what it does.

Can anyone tell me what to do to make my application scan and find the tag? Or is it for a specific application?

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth the remote device needs to make itself discoverable. Otherwise your scan will never find it. Each device will have a documented way to make itself discoverable. Read the manual for your device to find that out. It's usually pressing one of the buttons. I don't have the 621 manual but the below ebay page says: "Press the button 3 seconds to activate R621 when use it for the first time." My educated guess without having the device is that is how you make it discoverable. So do that and then run your scan.

http://m.ebay.in/itmdescription?itemId=251723268568

Comment: i did what you have said and nothing happen with my application , it  just response to rtrivr app and bluetooth scanner. i don't know what they write in the code to read the tag.